# WebView do react-native exibindo as tags html

Tags: javascript, html, react-native, webview, html-tags

Boa tarde, estou utilizando o WebView no react native para renderizar alguns componentes que vem da minha api no formato de string, o problema é que o WebView não reconhece as tags presentes na string.

segue abaixo parte do código:

```
<WebView
    source={{ html: ocorrenciaSelecionada.ocorrencia}}
    style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', width: contentWidth}}
/>
```

ocorrenciaSelecionada.ocorrencia é uma string que tem o seguinte conteúdo:

<p>Favor, alterar o valor do boleto da títular. O valor atual é de 417 reais. O valor correto é &nbsp;367,88 reais. Fico no aguardo. Obrigada. </p><p><br></p>

O problema é que o WebView está exibindo as tags como texto ao invés de lê-las.
Como faço para que o WebView reconheça as tags?

Fiz o seguinte teste e funcionou corretamente:

```
<WebView
    source={{ html: "<h1>teste</h1>"}}
    style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', width: contentWidth}}
/>
```

assim ele funciona corretamente, porém eu preciso que renderize o conteúdo vindo da API...
Desde já agradeço toda ajuda